# Tranlating UserStore(Of ApplicationUser, IdentityRole) vb code to C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-identity

Can somebody help me convert this Visual Basic code to C#. I am trying to use SQLite as a database for EF Identity, but only sample I find is in VS.

```vb
Public Class UserManager

    Inherits UserManager(Of ApplicationUser)

    Public Sub New()

        MyBase.New(New UserStore(Of ApplicationUser, IdentityRole)(New ApplicationDbContext()))

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the C# version.

```
public class UserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public UserManager() : 
        base(new UserStore<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()))
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Amanda. It works perfectly. Now I can use SQLite for user logging in . The vb code is at http://noob-programmer-journal.blogspot.com/2018/01/aspnet-identity-sqlite-provider-on-web.html .